# php for each loop not functioning

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to clean up a database table that might be missing book titles or bio information.  The user is supposed to be able to click a button and the program does the rest.
I have run the query in my database and it returns the information I am looking for, so i think my issue is with the for each loop.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once ('../db.php');
    require_once ('../amazon/amazon.php');
    $conn = db_connect();
    session_start();
    $x = 0;

    // find all of the books with no Titles or Bios
    $result = $conn->query("
        select 
            i.date_created, 
            users.username, 
            i.sku,
            i.isbn13,
            i.quantity, 
            source.source,
            i.date_process, 
            location.location 
        from inventory i
            left join book on i.isbn13 = book.isbn13
            left join source on i.source_id = source.source_id
            left join location on i.location_id = location.location_id
            left join users on i.created_by = users.user_id
        where sku > '10000000' 
            and quantity >= 1 
            and (book.title = ''  
                 or book.title is null  
                 or book.author = '' 
                 or book.author is null) 
            and i.isbn13 >1");

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_rows > 0)
    { 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $isbnArray[$x] = $row['isbn13'];
            $qtyArray[$x] = $row['quantity'];
            $x++;
        } // end of while loop
    $sum = array_sum($qtyArray);
        for each ($isbnArray as $isbn)
        {
            //retrieve amazon data
            $parsed_xml = amazon_xml($isbn);
            $amazonResult = array();

            $current = $parsed_xml->Items->Item;

            if($parsed_xml->Items->Request->IsValid == 'True') {
                $amazonResult = array(
                    'Title' => $current->ItemAttributes->Title,
                    'Author' => $current->ItemAttributes->Author,
                    'Edition' => $current->ItemAttributes->Edition,
                    'Weight' => ($current->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight / 100),
                    'Publisher' => $current->ItemAttributes->Publisher,
                    'PublishDate' => $current->ItemAttributes->PublicationDate,
                    'Binding' => $current->ItemAttributes->Binding,
                    'SalesRank' => $current->SalesRank,
                    'ListPrice' => str_replace('$','',$current->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice),
                    'ImageURL' => $current->LargeImage->URL,
                    'DetailURL' => $current->DetailPageURL      
                );
        } // end of if statement

        //update Title and Bio info in book table
        $conn->query("
            update book 
            set isbn13 = '$isbn', 
                author = '" . $amazonResult['Author'] . "', 
                title ='" . $amazonResult['Title'] . "',
                edition =  '" . $amazonResult['Edition'] . "', 
                weight = '" . $amazonResult['Weight'] . "', 
                publisher = '" . $amazonResult['Publisher'] . "',
                binding = '" . $amazonResult['Binding'] . "', 
                listed_price = '" . $amazonResult['ListPrice'] . "', 
                pub_date = '" . $amazonResult['PublishDate'] . "'
            WHERE isbn13 = '$isbn'");
        } // end of for each loop
    }

    $message = array( 'message' => $sum.' Records were updated' );
    $conn->close();

    echo json_encode($message);
?>
```

To me everything looks right, but when I run it with firebug on, there is no message.  Console.log(data) in my success function says empty string.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I restructure my for each loop?

EDIT: I changed parts of the code to get an accurate count of how many records were updated. This is the $qtyArray[$x] = $row['quantity'] line. My console.log(data) shows that 2995 records were updated, but the #message does not appear on the screen, just the console.log(data).  Hope this gives a little more insight.

Comment: `foreach` is one word. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: how do you access this code with JavaScript? Console.log() is not in PHP

Comment: @TusharDhoot Indeed. The SO highlighter already tells you so. :)

Comment: The correct string concatenation operator is `.`, not `+`

Comment: @ Rene Pot yes, this is accessed through Javascript.  @ Tushar - Thanks for spotting that, it is now changed, but the result is still the same

Comment: @ afuzzyllama - Instead of editing my code to make it look neat and giving the question a down vote, how about giving some constructive information, I am trying to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I see you said that you updated your code, but as @TusharDhoot said, you still need to change "for each" to "foreach".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error may lie in your while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $isbnArray[$x] = $row['isbn13'];
        $sum = array_sum($isbnArray);
} // end of while loop
```

$x is initialized to 0, and never changed, so you just overwrite the same entry in the array each time.

You have to change:

```
$isbnArray[$x] = $row['isbn13'];
```

to:

```
$isbnArray[] = $row['isbn13'];
```

Comment: Is it better to do that or put $x++ just before the end of the while loop?

Comment: @Jim It really doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ok changed it to your suggestion, still no results. Thanks for taking a look, always nice to have another set of eyes check code you have stared at for hours

Comment: No problem. Are you sure your first query is returning results?

Comment: I ran it in Navicat and got 2007 records

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your " in your query

```
$result = $conn->query("
    select 
        i.date_created, 
        users.username, 
        i.sku,
        i.isbn13,
        i.quantity, 
        source.source,
        i.date_process, 
        location.location 
    from inventory i
        left join book on i.isbn13 = book.isbn13
        left join source on i.source_id = source.source_id
        left join location on i.location_id = location.location_id
        left join users on i.created_by = users.user_id
    where sku > '10000000' 
        and quantity >= 1 
        and (book.title = \"\"  
             or book.title is null  
             or book.author = \"\" 
             or book.author is null) 
        and i.isbn13 >1");
```

Comment: When I change my code to your suggestion, I get a mysql error, so I looked it up and it was suggested that I use '' instead. I did this and my message says that 18500525410454835 Records were updated.  I don't even have that many records in my database. Any thoughts?  It should only reference 1800 - 2000 records. I have updated the original code to reflect what I now have.

Comment: I think you should try and go step by step in your code to find where the problem is. Start off by placing print_r($result); die; so you can see what $results contains and not run anything else. If it looks right, then move on down. print_r($result->fetch_assoc()); etc... You can also use var_dump($results);

Comment: I ran the print_r($result);die; right after my query and got mysqli_result Object ( ). I don't understand, the query works fine in Navicat but not from the php file.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's the query, just trying to find where the issue is. 
Ok, we have the object. Now work your way down to see if what you need in is correct. Since your are doing a SELECT then you should have rows of data, so try print_r($result->fetch_assoc()); to see if you get an array of data. If not, then the next question is do you have valid connection to your DB?

Comment: When I run print_r($isbnArray); die; right after my while loop, I get 1884 isbn records. Which is what i should have, so it seems my query is good.

Comment: I just noticed is that you said you have a very high updated record count. I see that you take the i.quantity and put it in an array, then add the array together and say that is how many updated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12561/discussion-between-jim-and-hitmandx)